# Async Operation completion in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am using a 3rd party library ([ng2-img-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-img-tools.)) to perform a image resize.
The library is providing different functions to perform image resizing such as

resize,
crop,
resizeExactCrop.

The above functions are asynchronous operations.

For eg.

```
 resizeImage(files:any, width:number, height:number){
    return this.ng2ImgToolsService.resize(files, width, height)
    .map((result:any) => result)
    .catch((error:any) => error);
  }

  //For Thumbnails
  resizeExactCrop(files:any, width:number, height:number){
    return this.ng2ImgToolsService.resizeExactCrop(files, width, height)
    .map((result:any) => result)
    .catch((error:any) => error);
  }
```

I am calling above 2 functions to resize the image.

```
resizeImages(){
     this.resizeImage([img1],400,400).subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Resized Image is "+data); //1st finished
    },
    error => console.log("Resizing Image Failed", error));

     this.resizeExactCrop([img1],100,100).subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Cropped Image is "+data); //2nd finished
    },
    error => console.log("Resizing Image Failed", error));
   }
```

I need to perform an operation, when above 2 operations in the `resizeImages` are finished. How can i track whether the two operations are completed. I am using counter to track the async operation completion. Is there any way to track completion efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**RxJS#forkJoin**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) function - when all observables complete, emit their last values. You can write

```
Observable.forkJoin(
   this.resizeImage([img1],400,400),
   this.resizeExactCrop([img1],100,100)
).subscribe(values => ...)
```

Example of code. The Observable subscribe works only when all Observables are completed (one of them works with 2 seconds delay)

```js
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

console.log('Start');

Observable.forkJoin(
  Observable.of(4),
  Observable.of('Hello').delay(2000)
).subscribe(values => console.log(values));
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.4.3/dist/global/Rx.js'></script>
```

Comment: I tried forkJoin, but 'values' are not getting called inside subscribe. Do i need return anything inside 'resizeImage' and 'resizeExactCrop'.

Comment: yes. i was able to call separately and get the result.

Comment: I think this will work for you. Try to work in some ways with this sample code

Comment: I am able to get the values in the subscribe when i use first value. for eg., this.resizeImage([img1],400,400).first()

Comment: it is discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/617

Comment: I think know what can be the problem. Are your observables return one value or infinite ? If infinite, the forkJoin will never complete

Comment: it's not infinite. It's just returns the single blob.